# Not able to Authenticate using RSA 2048 Keys

Tags: ssh, rsa, openssh

As I am doing my routine penetration testing and found the vulnerability in which OpenSSH have weak RSA-2048 and DSA-1024 keys.

So, I have downloaded the exploit for the same and got some weak keys. 
Now, when I am trying to authenticate into the system using RSA private key/ Public key. It still ask me for the password.

I have used the way

`ssh -i /my/keys/location user@IPaddress`

But, the conceptually, while using RSA keys for the authentication, it should not ask for the password.

May be you will think that, the RSA keys are not present in `authorized_keys`

The keys are founded by using bruteforcing so they are present in authroized_keys.

Any comment or suggestion regarding the same are most welcome.

Regards

Comment: 1. it could simply be that the key itselve is password protected, 2. it could be that the server simply is configured to use password based authentication instead of keys and 3. it could be that the key fails and the server is configured to fall back to password authentication. Whilst that is not exactly secure it cannot be considered a vulnerability, since this is a configuration thing.

Comment: Also your last statement about the usage of brute force makes absolutely no sense to me here. I doubt you want to express that the keys have been found by brute forcing the openssh server you are trying to penetrate, or do you?

Comment: Stackoverflow is for [programming questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), thus this question is off-topic here. With more details it might be on-topic in [superuser.com](http://superuser.com/).